# 'Unable to connect' but Youtube and Wikipedia work fine, can't update or search software store

Tags: 20.04

Brand new user to Linux, fresh install of 20.04 LTS.

I am getting a 'Unable to connect' on Firefox, but from firefox I can load and watch youtube just fine, as well as some limited websites like Wikipedia. Search queries come back just fine with links to videos and articles, but once clicking on them I get a 'Unable to connect'. I also cannot search/update the software app.

Terminal seems to be working fine, was able to install net tools and able was able to connect during install for updates.

I have no idea where to go from this point.

Hardware: Samsung Galaxy Book Flex Alpha, core i5 10th gen, 250gb SSD, 8gb ram.
My other computer and phone are able to connect wirelessly no problem on the same network, even tried disconnecting everything and still same problem with ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried setting the MTU?
https://superuser.com/questions/213264/cant-access-select-websites-on-linux-but-can-on-windows